# Can I use std::vector::swap to modify a shared vector?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++98

I'm working on software where multiple threads read-access a single `std::vector` with a lot (and large) data.

I have some basic understanding of the complexities of multiple theads accessing a single object and things can be greatly simplified by using a mutex.

In my case, modifying an existing object is a lot more expensive that copying it. So I was thinking about creating a copy, modifing the copy (while not holding the mutex) and
then swapping it back into the shared object.

I cannot use C++11, so I don't have access to move operations, but it is my understanding that `gcc` uses a very efficient `std::vector::swap()` that is comparable with move operations (in terms of speed).

I was thinking about something like this:

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx;

class bigdata_t { ... };
std::vector<bigdata_t> shared_vec; // accessed by multiple threads

void modify_bigdata()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    std::vector<bigdata_t> tmp_vec = shared_vec; // create copy
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    /*
     * Here, apply expensive modifications to tmp_vec
     */

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    shared_vec.swap(tmp_vec); // this is very fast and does not copy data
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}
```

`modify_bigdata()` is only called by a single thread, so this is basically a single writer/multiple reader approach.

It runs very fast, but swapping data back into the shared vector kind of feels like cheating.

My question is:
Is this approach correct and thread-safe ?

Comment: You didn't give `bigdata_t` its own `swap` member?

Comment: if two threads call modify_bigdata(), each makes a copy and modify their copies concurrently, then one could swap, and the other straight after, loosing one of your threads modifications. You would surely want to keep all modifications by all threads so you must lock, modify, unlock and ditch the copy & swap and inner unlock() and lock()

Comment: As long as there are no concurrent calls to `modify_bigdata`, this should work. I don't see what's *cheating* about calling a function that does what you want. Do note that your mutex remains locked if the `vector` copy throws an exception. You can avoid that by using an RAII wrapper for the mutex, for instance Boost has a `scoped_lock` that implements this.

Comment: Good point.. the call to `modify_bigdata` is only executed by a single thread

Comment: You should say in your question there is a single writer and all other threads are readers - in which case it is as @Praetorian said.

Comment: "Modifying an existing object is a lot more expensive that copying it" - But then you copy, modify, and swap... How is this supposed to be more efficient than a single modify, since you end up modifying a copy? If that is because of locking, then your question isn't phrased correctly...

Comment: **This is dangerous** to do that as reader threads might have pointers or iterators to elements of the vector that was "active" before the swap and those could become invalid afterward if the original vector is modified or destroyed afterward.

Comment: @Macmade The point is that the mutex is unlocked while the expensive modification is done to reduce contention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you swap the whole vector, it is very dangerous if any reader thread has reference inside that vector as when swapping, it is very possible that the other vector get destroyed in which case any reference from reader threads can become invalide.

So every time your reader thread would access the vector, they would need a lock. So using swap won't help here. The only way it could works is that by ensuring that no reader are active by using some kind of multiple reader - single writer lock.

What might works for you is

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<bigdata_t>> shared_vec;
```

That way, you only need to properly synchronize the exchange of pointers and ensure that either:

- the size of the vector does not change once you have started reader threads or
- that you never keep iterator around and access to vector is properly synchronized.

Comment: Good point about potentially dangling references. It does not apply to my particular case, but I did not mention that in the question.